# How to DISTINCT one column in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, distinct

I wrote one stored procedure.

My requirement is i have to show  the data like if any No column has different Account_Names i have to show like  Account_Name :Multipul(varchar))

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[OpenVendorBIllsSP] (@FromDate Date,@ToDate Date) 
AS 
BEGIN 
select
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by vendor.VendorName ) AS ID,
PH.PurchasingHeaderID as No,
PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency as Balance,
acc.AccountName as [Account_Name],
PD.LineMemo as Memo,
from PurchasingHeader PH
LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionType Trans ON PH.TransactionTypeID =Trans.TransactionTypeID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor vendor on PH.VendorID=vendor.VendorID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PaymentTerm PT on PT.PaymentTermID = vendor.PaymentTermID
LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchasingDetail PD on PD.PurchasingHeaderID = PH.PurchasingHeaderID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Account Acc on Acc.AccountID= PD.FinancialAccountID 
where PH.TransactionTypeID=7
Group by vendor.VendorName,
PH.PurchasingHeaderID,PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency,acc.AccountName
END
GO
```

with this result:

```
ID       No          Account_Name            Balance   Memo**
-------------------------------------------------------------
 101      VB1000        Cash-Petty Cash           4000.00  Memo
 102     VB1001        Accounts Receivable        5000.00  Memo
 103    VB1003       Cash-PettyCash             6000.00  Memo
 104     VB1003       Cash-PettyCash            6000.00  Memo
 105    VB1004        UndepositedFunds          7000.00  Memo
```

I need this result :

```
ID      No        Account_Name          Balance    Memo
------------------------------------------------------
 101      VB1000      Cash-PettyCash        4000.00   Memo1
 102      VB1001      AccountsReceivable     5000.00   Memo2
 103     VB1003      ---Multiple----        6000.00   Memo3
 104     VB1004      UndepositedFunds      7000.00   Memo4
```

Can any one tell me how can i write the sp to get aboue result.

Edited SP :

select

ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by vendor.VendorName ) AS ZID,

PH.PurchasingHeaderID as No,

PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency as Balance,

**Case When count(PH.PurchasingHeaderID) > 1 Then 'Multipul' else acc.AccountName END**

from PurchasingHeader PH

LEFT OUTER JOIN TransactionType Trans ON PH.TransactionTypeID =Trans.TransactionTypeID

LEFT OUTER JOIN Vendor vendor on PH.VendorID=vendor.VendorID

LEFT OUTER JOIN PaymentTerm PT on PT.PaymentTermID = vendor.PaymentTermID

LEFT OUTER JOIN PurchasingDetail PD on PD.PurchasingHeaderID = PH.PurchasingHeaderID

LEFT OUTER JOIN Account Acc on Acc.AccountID= PD.FinancialAccountID

where PH.TransactionTypeID=7

Group by vendor.VendorName,PH.PurchasingHeaderID ,

PH.PurchasingHeaderID,PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency,acc.AccountName

Answer (score 0):

You could do a subsection that has everything, then `GROUP BY acc.AccountName, PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency`, etc and do a `CASE WHERE COUNT(acc.AccountName) > 1`

Comment: i am new to sql. can you tell me where i have to write this case statement.

Comment: Instead of going `SELECT foo FROM bar` you can try 
`SELECT CASE foo           
      WHEN 1 THEN 'true'
      ELSE 'false'
END 
FROM bar`

Comment: i wrote case statement in select list.But i did not get ' Multipul' string. let me know where i am doing mistake. (i have edited Question)

Comment: You will probably need to subselect so that COUNT counts the duplicates and not counts everything

Comment: I can't really test your code or anything but hopefully this will inspire you :)

`SELECT ZID, No, Balance, Case When count(acc.AccountName) > 1 Then 'Multipul' else acc.AccountName END
FROM (
 SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order by vendor.VendorName ) AS ZID,
  PH.PurchasingHeaderID as No,
  PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency as Balance,
  acc.AccountName
 --YOUR FROM AND JOIN STATEMENTS
 where PH.TransactionTypeID = 7
) TempTable
Group by vendor.VendorName,PH.PurchasingHeaderID,
PH.PurchasingHeaderID,PH.TotalPriceCompanyCurrency,acc.AccountName`

Comment: i am sorry, i did not understand this.why this Temp Table .Can you elaborate little bit more.

Comment: This is so that you can get ALL records, then GROUP/COUNT your duplicates, whilst retaining the SINGLE records that are already there and not excluding them.